# XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, xampp

I installed XAMPP in my Ubuntu laptop and I used to work with it without a problem. Just starting the server with:

`sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`

Then, I tried to install a software that needed an apache server and probably something screwed it. Now, each time I run the command, I have this output:

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.3-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

What I have to do, is to run the `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop` and then start the lampp again. This means that the apache2 is running all the time. Is there any way to solve it without destroy the lampp installation too?

Answer (score 26):

The reason for the message `Starting Apache... fail` it's because the `apache2` service is already running(`enabled`) while our system starts. We can check that using:

`sudo systemctl status apache2`

These two commands will solve the problem but **NOT** permanently.

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop`

`sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`

We can disable the `apache2` service so that it won't start everytime we boot our system:

`sudo systemctl disable apache2`

This will solve the issue but I'm not sure if disabling a service is a good idea.

Comment: And after the next reboot?